# Is there C# raw string with delimiter like in C++?

Tags: c#, c++, string

In C++, we have raw literal string using R"()" with delimiter. So this code below is fine:

```
const char SOMETEXT[] = R"+-+-+(<link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.png">)+-+-+"
```

I don't know how to do it in C#, as far as i know there is a verbatim string using @"" but it doesn't have delimiter. And this causes error:

```
string SOMETEXT = @"<link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.png">";
```

Is there any raw literal string with delimiter in C#? Because i don't want to change the string, it will PITA to edit later.

Comment: you are thinking about it in the wrong way.   strings in C# are first class citizens, which are unicode (or UTF16), not just arrays of chars (as they are in C/C++).   What is it that you are trying solve?

Comment: @Neil OP's C++ example just happens to be an array of chars. C++ has `std::string` and also has for example the `u8` prefix for UTF-8 encoded literals. You're either thinking about C or archaic C++. Remember: In C++ you don't pay for what you don't need/use. C# is different in that matter, here performance is not a 'first class citizen'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's nothing like this in C#. If this is arbitrary text that you'll need to edit reasonably frequently, you might want to put it into a resource file instead.

Another alternative I often use for JSON that appears in tests etc is to just use single quotes instead of double quotes, then replace afterwards:

```
string text = "<link rel='icon' href='img/favicon.png'>".Replace('\'', '"');
```

Answer (score 3):

In an `@`ed string (aka *a verbatim string literal*) you can use `""` for double qoutes.

```
string SOMETEXT = @"<link rel=""icon"" href=""img/favicon.png"">";
```

In a regular string literal you can use a backslash.

```
string someText2 = "<link rel=\"icon\" href=\"img/favicon.png\">";
```

---

### More on differences between verbatin and standard string literals

Please note that only the quote escape sequence ("") in not interpreted  literally in a verbatim literal string; all others are taken literally.

Here is an example from [@ (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim).

> The following example illustrates the effect of defining a regular string literal and a verbatim string literal that contain identical character sequences.
>
> ```
> string s1 = "He said, \"This is the last \u0063hance\x0021\"";
> string s2 = @"He said, ""This is the last \u0063hance\x0021""";
>
> Console.WriteLine(s1);
> Console.WriteLine(s2);
> // The example displays the following output:
> //     He said, "This is the last chance!"
> //     He said, "This is the last \u0063hance\x0021"
> ```

---

## I don't want to change the string!

If you don't want to change the string you can embed it as a file. For unit testing I often store json files as embedded resources and load them with `GetManifestResourceStream`.

Comment: I still don't quite understand the question, but this seems the most likely answer (nothing to do with delimeters, but actually escaping).